# How to directly run x11-apps(xeyes, glxgears) in colab hostruntime?

Tags: google-colaboratory, x11

I know there are some solutions like x11-forwarding(ngrok), TurboVNC(virtualgl) could be useful. However, is that possible to directly run x11-apps in colab?

I firstly installed xvfb and pyvirtualdisplay and then run !xeyes in colab, but what I saw was an endless loop.

[image]

My code in two cells:

```
!apt-get install xvfb x11-utils
!apt-get install -y x11-apps
!pip install pyvirtualdisplay
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
Display(visible=0, size=(1000, 1000)).start()

!xeyes
```

It is my first time asking a question on StackOverflow, and it would be hard to render some 3D program on a cloud(colab hostruntime), but I would appreciate any help.